# The new ugly terminal. I don't like it. How i can change the style?

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux

Today is my first day using kali on my virtualbox. I dont know if this a problem or not. But i want to change this thing:

[image: [New terminal]]

to:

[image: Old terminal kali]

I dont like the new ugly terminal style. How can I change it?

Comment: If you type `bash` does it change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `chsh bash` to permanently change your shell from `zsh` to `bash`.

That said, you might want to read about [OhMyZsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) and improve your day-to-day usage instead.